# Extending the built in Windows Phone 8 Map control

Tags: windows-phone-8

For educational purposes, I want to extend the WP8 Map control to add a property for the current location (e.g so I can call myMap.CurrentLocation) and then use this custom control in my XAML template. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it wasn't sealed you could just inherit form it and add whatever other properties you want.

Unfortunately it is sealed so I'd suggest creating a new UserControl which includes a map instance and then add whatever other properties you want to that control. Make the new properties either regular ones or DependencyProperties as necessary you could also create wrapper properties to those of the map control or expose the inner control directly. It will depend on your specific use cases.